# tfds.features.Video Usage for video decoding in tensorflow 2

Tags: ffmpeg, deep-learning, video-processing, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to decode a video in tensorflow 2 using tfds.features.Video , so that the output is a "tf.Tensor of type tf.uint8 and shape [num_frames, height, width, channels]" using following code :

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
df_trains= pd.DataFrame()
df_trains['video_files']= ['aa.mp4']

files_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(df_trains.video_files)

video_class = tfds.features.Video(shape=(None, 1080, 1920,3), encoding_format='png', ffmpeg_extra_args=())

a= video_class.decode_example(files_ds)
```

However it generates following error: 
`"AssertionError: Feature Video can only be decoded when defined as top-level feature, through info.features.decode_example()"`

I am unable to solve it, please help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `tfds.features.Video` like that. `tfds.features.Video` is commonly used with `tfds.builder` or `tfds.load`.

So when you use `tfds_download_dataset`, you feel comfortable, but hard to use custom dataset.

```
features = tfds.features.FeaturesDict({
    'video': tfds.features.Video(shape=(None, 1080, 1920,3)),
})
tfds.load(..., decoders=features, ...)
```

But `tfds.features.Video` can be used by making `my_dataset` including your data.

However, it's very annoying. So `cv2` is better than that.

Comment: Thanks it is of great help. As you said for custom dataset, may you explain a bit more, how may I use it on my own mp4 videos dataset let's say of 2  videos:  "a.mp4" and "b.mp4" .